# Convert a column in-place on CSV

Tags: awk, date, csv, gawk

I need some help on date conversion in-place on a CSV.
Basically, I was capable to convert the column and save in a new file, but I was unable  to save it on the original CSV.

I have a CSV with date format `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM` and I want to convert to `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM`, it's the first column of my CSV.

My CSV file has something like that:

```
29/01/2018 14:07,payable,37159871,,30521316
29/01/2018 14:07,payable,37159872,,30521316
29/01/2018 14:07,payable,37159870,,30521316
29/01/2018 14:07,payable,37159869,,30521316
29/01/2018 14:07,payable,37159868,,30521316
```

And I want to have something like that:

```
2018-01-29 14:07,payable,37159871,,30521316
2018-01-29 14:07,payable,37159872,,30521316
2018-01-29 14:07,payable,37159870,,30521316
2018-01-29 14:07,payable,37159869,,30521316
2018-01-29 14:07,payable,37159868,,30521316
```

What I was capable to do:

```
gawk -F, '{split($1, a, "/| "); print a[3]"-"a[2]"-"a[1]" "a[4]}' /path/to/file.csv > test_file
```

So now I want to know how can I save this back on my CSV file.

Comment: No simple way if you use `awk`, just rename it later.

Comment: If you have a sufficiently new version of `gawk` you may be able to use the [in-place extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Inplace.html#Extension-Sample-Inplace)

Comment: or see `sponge` in moreutils

Comment: run `mv test_file /path/to/file.csv`, to overwrite the old file with the new file afterwards.

Comment: The `test_file` only contain the first column of the CSV file...

Comment: Append `$2, $3, $4` to your awk command, set `OFS=,` if necessary. If the file isn't too big (it doesn't seem to be), `sponge` may save you some trouble in writing back to the original file.

Comment: the file above its just an example... it has 15k lines and more columns...

Comment: Sorry, do you want the separator in the output file for the first field to be "-" or "/"? Your script is inconsistent with your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The edit in this case is so simple I wouldn't bother with Awk.

With GNU Sed it's as simple as:

```
sed -rie 's_^(..)/(..)/(....)_\3-\2-\1_' file.csv
```

With BSD Sed, use:

```
sed -Ei '' -e 's_^(..)/(..)/(....)_\3-\2-\1_' file.csv
```

With POSIX tools only it's a bit uglier but not terrible:

```
printf '%s\n' '%s/^\(..\)\/\(..\)\/\(....\)/\3-\2-\1/' x | ex file.csv
```

Edit: Actually a closer look at the [POSIX specs for `ex`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html) reveals that (almost) any delimiter may be used, just as in Sed.  So:

```
printf '%s\n' '%s_^\(..\)/\(..\)/\(....\)_\3-\2-\1_' x | ex file.csv
```

*Slightly* better.

Answer (score 0):

Given that awk has no built-in "in-place editing" option (usually implemented as a behind-the-scenes copy anyway), and ever since reading [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186126/117549), my preferred solution in this scenario is of the form:

> cp input_file temp_file  &&  command … temp_file > input_file  &&  rm temp_file

For your situation:

```
cp /path/to/file.csv temp_file &&
gawk -F, '{split($1, a, "/| "); print a[3]"-"a[2]"-"a[1]" "a[4]}' < temp_file > /path/to/file.csv &&
rm temp_file
```

Note the `&&` syntax which ties the commands together and executes subsequent commands only if the previous ones were successful.

Comment: OP has commented that the script only gives the first column and there are many columns (much more than 4 I think) ...

Comment: Thank you, I didn't catch that aspect of it; I was responding to the `So now I want to know how can I save this back on my CSV file.` part.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using GNU awk:

```
gawk -i inplace -F, ...
```

and if you want to keep a backup of the original

```
gawk -i inplace -v INPLACE_SUFFIX=".bak" -F, ...
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Inplace.html#Extension-Sample-Inplace

Comment: Beware [using gawk -i inplace like that introduces a security vulnerability](/q/749645) unless you modify `$AWKPATH` not to include `.` or make sure you run that command from within a working directory where nobody could create a file called `inplace` or `inplace.awk`.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved the same by using below awk command

input.csv

```
2018-01-29 14:07,payable,37159871,,30521316
2018-01-29 14:07,payable,37159872,,30521316
2018-01-29 14:07,payable,37159870,,30521316
2018-01-29 14:07,payable,37159869,,30521316
2018-01-29 14:07,payable,37159868,,30521316
```

command

```
awk '{gsub("/","-",$0);print $0}' input.csv| awk -F "-" '{print $3,$2,$1}'  | awk -F " " '{print $1"-"$(NF -1)"-"$NF,$2}'
```

output

```
2018-01-29 14:07,payable,37159871,,30521316
2018-01-29 14:07,payable,37159872,,30521316
2018-01-29 14:07,payable,37159870,,30521316
2018-01-29 14:07,payable,37159869,,30521316
2018-01-29 14:07,payable,37159868,,30521316
```

Comment: It looks to me like they've already managed to use awk to change the format; what about the actual question at the end: `So now I want to know how can I save this back on my CSV file.` ?